# how to print value in controller in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

am using code as below but am not getting any value.i gave as  print_r($this->title); what i have to do to get the value. thanks

```
            if(isset($_POST['is_ajax']) && $_POST['is_ajax']) {
            print_r($this->title);
        $respondentArray = array(
            'state' => $_POST['state'],
            'name' => $_POST['name'],
            'title' => $_POST['title'],
            'dline' => $_POST['directline'],
            'email' => $_POST['email'],
            'organization' => $_POST['organization'],
            'address' => $_POST['address'],
            'city' => $_POST['city'],
            'state1' => $_POST['state1'],
            'zip' => $_POST['zip'],
            'generalphone' => $_POST['generalphone'],
            'fax' => $_POST['fax'],
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($respondentArray);
```

Comment: where is $this->title coming from? Form, preset in controller... (also for an ajax request check the input class has a is_ajax_request method)

Comment: normally can you say how to print the values

Comment: to access a from value (assuming it has been POSTed just follow the example in bipen's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess this is what you need

```
  echo $this->input->post('title') ;
```

`$this->input->post(postedValues)` this gets all the input values that is posted...

Comment: yes you can.... but not `print_r()` that is to print an array.. and this is not an array.. :)

Comment: then how to print single value

Comment: am not able to see any output

Answer (score 0):

Use `var_dump($this->title);` to test